# JSON to realm object mapping issue iOS Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, realm

creating new model object by passing a dictionary just like this

```
let article = Article(value: json)
```

the Article object is

```
import RealmSwift
import Foundation

class Article: Object {
   dynamic var id = 0
```

and i get this error every time

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Invalid value '173' for property 'id''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Disclaimer: I work for Realm)*

That exception gets thrown if the data type of the item in the dictionary doesn't match the expected data type of the Realm property.

In this instance, I'm getting the feeling that `id` is coming down as a string (Is it in quotes in the JSON string?), so subsequently trying to map it to an integer property won't work.

If this isn't the case, please see if you can post a copy of your JSON string so we can see if we can work out better what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: What purpose does your disclaimer serve? To add credibility to your answer? If the disclaimer is true, your answer will be *by default* very credible, thus there is no need for superfluous words.

Comment: I just want to absolutely avoid any confusion or potentially perceived ill-will of hiding that fact when specifically answering a question about it. :) Duly noted. I'll put it at the end in future.

Comment: you are right, but why wouldn't realm try to cast/convert the string to int when the data type is int, and only throw an error when value cannot be cast?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for that! That's a good question. That might have been done by design (To minimize code complexity), or it may still be a pending feature. If you think it's something that Realm should have, feel free to open an issue on the Realm-Cocoa GitHub repo!

Comment: I think that it is suitable to replace "dynamic var id = 0" by "@objc dynamic var id = 0"

Comment: That's correct. Swift has changed a lot since this question was originally asked. Back then, `dynamic` alone implicitly indicated it was an Objective-C property.